# Galois group of a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}(x)$ and deck transformations of the covering of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, covering-spaces

Let $w(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be an irreducible polynomial. The vanishing locus $Z=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | w(x,y)=0 \}$ with projection to $x$-coordinate is a ramified covering $\pi : Z \to \mathbb{C}$. Lets remove ramification locus $D$ and get unramified (topological) covering  $\pi' : Z' \to \mathbb{C}\backslash D$. Denote $G_1$ the group of deck transformations of this covering.

On the other hand, we have finite extension of fields $\mathbb{C}(x) \to \mathbb{C}(x)[y]/(w(x,y))$, let $G_2$ be the group of automorhisms of the extension.

For coverings and for field extensions we have notion of normality. Is this covering normal iff extension is normal?

What are relations between groups $G_1$ and $G_2$? Are they isomorphic?

Comment: If we take projective closure first, I think G2 at least embeds into G1. This is because every field automorphism of Rat(Z) correspond to a birational map of Z and for projective varieties birational maps are isomorphisms

Comment: "for projective varieties birational maps are isomorphisms" Do you mean projective curves?

Comment: I think the following is a good strategy. The field $\mathbb{C}(x)[y]/(w(x,y)$ is exactly the field of rational functions on $Z$. So, we only need to compare ramified coverings of the line by curve $Z$ and corresponding topological coverings.

Comment: I think I meant smooth projective curves